# How use Android Universal Image Loader to catch image(s) and use them into layout background?

Tags: android, image, loader, universal

I'm doing some research on Universal Image Loader library and I found It awsome. But I have a doubt. I want to download an image from an URL, catch It into SD/Internal memory and use It into a Linear Layout Background. As far as I undestand AIL it catch images when you use the displayImage(..) methods. Does anyone know If It's possible to download an Image from URL, catch It and load It into a Bitmap to use It later into Layouts' backgrounds? I can accept any other solution to acomplish that. Thanks

EDIT

Just to be clear what I wanna do is
1.- Download an Image
2.- catch It
3.-load It as Bitmap so I can do something like that

```
 Bitmap b=(image catched by UIL);
 BitmapDrawable drawableBitmap=new BitmapDrawable(b);
 linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableBitmap);
```

Comment: What do you mean by catch It and load It into a Bitmap to use It later into Layouts' backgrounds? UIL is best used for displaying images in listview and gridview's

Comment: For your purpose i don't think you require UIL.

Comment: I mean If I can use It to catch images wich I want put as Layout Background, because If I can do that I will use It a lot and avoids me to use 2 implementations to load images, one for backgrounds (wich I have to build myself) and other for ImageViews (wich gives me UIL)

Comment: Ok, so If It's not a good idea, do you know How I can do that using the same app cache and have both ways working? I really need a backgrounds cache

Comment: you can cache bitmaps without using UIL http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html Use a asyntask or executor to download images. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: You probably mean cache, not catch.

Comment: Probably, sorry, not very good in English. I saw that way catch Bitmaps but I thougth that was a bad idea have 2 cache's for the same app

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to use the DiskLruCache but It's not recognized as a type, even adding the android-supportv4.jar. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to set downloaded image in layout.

```
      ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(pack.getCoverImageUrl(), new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
            rl_header_main.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage));
            rl_header_main.setAlpha();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            super.onLoadingCancelled(imageUri, view);
        }
    });
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Remove setAlpha();

Comment: rl_header_main.setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated